# how to import headers using target_link_libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I have one package and `CMakeList.txt` inside that package does

```
add_library(X y.cpp z.cpp)
```

`y.cpp` is including `A.h`.

I have another package B in which source files are using `A.h` from the first package.

Now one way to use these header files is do `catkin_make()`, `install()` and add package dependency.

But what if I don't want to include package dependency and instead of `target_link_library()` import header files from X? Can I just do `add_dependency(curret_target X)` without adding any package dependency? Do I still need `catkin_make()` and `install()` in first package?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated question.

Comment: Use `target_include_directories(X INTERFACE directory_with_x_includes)`.